# User can chose from a great amount of configurations/templates, need a way to handle without creating Django views/forms for every single one

Tags: python, django, database, forms

Currently i am working on a project in Django which will let the user generate a router/switch configuration based on what type of service/router brand/router model he chooses.

View: config list (List of registered configurations to generate)
User -> Service_1 for router X model Y

Then i would need to present the user with a page which will take the inputs needed to generate such configs

View: generate config (Form that will ask the user for inputs needed to create X config file)
Ex.:
IP Address / Subnet Mask / is DHCP needed / routes needed

This input will then be passed to variables which will be used to populate a jinja2 template file for said service/router model/router brand in a function

Assume the structure is:

```
-Router Brand X
--Model Y
---Service1.j2
---Service2.j2
---Service3.j2
--Model Z
---Service1.j2
---Service2.j2
---Service3.j2
-Router Brand Y
--Model Y
---Service1.j2
---Service2.j2
---Service3.j2
--Model Z
---Service1.j2
---Service2.j2
---Service3.j2
```

I have a big part of the project already done, right now i can save the config templates to my database, show said templates for the user to choose from and i gave it a try to create a page to generate the config.

The issue i have at this point is that if i keep doing what i was going to do,
-Create a function, form and view for every new config template
i will have a big issue trying to scale later on.

We have around 10-12 services but there is around 5 different brands of routers/switches and then a lot of models that we still support (This project is for an ISP)

This is the process atm:

views.py

```
def ar651_ftth_datavpn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ar651_ftth_datavpn_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            hostname = form.cleaned_data['hostname']
            is_dhcp = form.cleaned_data['is_dhcp']
            gateway = form.cleaned_data['gateway']
            ip_rede = form.cleaned_data['ip_rede']
            excluded_ip = form.cleaned_data['excluded_ip']
            exIpList_str = form.cleaned_data['exIpList']
            exIpList = exIpList_str.split(',')
            ip_LanNet = form.cleaned_data['ip_LanNet']
            ip_LanNetSubmask = form.cleaned_data['ip_LanNetSubmask']
            localizacao = form.cleaned_data['localizacao']
            
            file_path = func_ar651_ftth_datavpn(hostname, is_dhcp, gateway, ip_rede, excluded_ip, exIpList, ip_LanNet, ip_LanNetSubmask, localizacao)
            return FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
    else:
        form = ar651_ftth_datavpn_form()

    return render(request, 'ar651_ftth_datavpn.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class ar651_ftth_datavpn_form(forms.Form):
    
    loc_escolha = [
        ('SUL', 'Sul'),
        ('NORTE', 'Norte'),
        ('CENTRO', 'Centro'),
    ]
    
    hostname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    localizacao = forms.CharField(label="Localizacao", widget=forms.Select(choices=loc_escolha))
    is_dhcp = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    gateway = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    ip_rede = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    excluded_ip = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    exIpList = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    ip_LanNet = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    ip_LanNetSubmask = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
```

generate config func

```
def func_ar651_ftth_datavpn(hostname, is_dhcp, gateway, ip_rede, excluded_ip, exIpList, ip_LanNet, ip_LanNetSubmask, localizacao):
    
    if is_dhcp is False:
        gateway = ''
        ip_rede = ''
        
    if excluded_ip is False:
        exIpList = ''
    router_vars = {
        'hostname': hostname,
        'is_dhcp': is_dhcp,
        'gateway': gateway,
        'ip_rede': ip_rede,
        'excluded_ip': excluded_ip,
        'localizacao': localizacao,
        'exIpList': exIpList,
        'ipLanNet': ip_LanNet,
        'ip_LanNetSubmask': ip_LanNetSubmask,
    }
```

At this point i have only created a form, view and generate func for a single config template.